# redux saga run other middleware before get into sagaMiddleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have this codes:

```
// jwtmiddleware.js //

function createJwtMiddleware() {
    return ({ dispatch, getState }) => (next) => (action) => {
        const auth = getState().auth;
        if (typeof action === 'function') {
            if (auth && auth.token) {
                const exp = jwtDecode(auth.token).exp;

                const tokenExpiration = moment.unix(exp);
                if (tokenExpiration && (
                        tokenExpiration.diff(moment(), 'm') <= 8
                    )) {
                    return authPromise(dispatch).then(() => setTimeout(next(action), 250));
                }
            }
        }

        return next(action);
    };

}
```

And put it into store.js:

```
const middlewares = [
    jwt,
    thunk,
    routerMiddleware(history),
    sagaMiddleware,
];
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__;

const store = createStore(reducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)));
export default store;
```

my saga:

```
export function menuRequest() {
    return { type: FETCH_MENU_REQUEST };
}

function fetchMenu() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.get('/menus')
            .then((response) => resolve(response))
            .catch((error) => reject(error))
    })
}

export function* handleFetchMenu() {
    try {
        const payload = yield call(fetchMenu);

        yield put({ type: FETCH_MENU_SUCCESS, payload });
    } catch (e) {
        yield put({ type: FETCH_MENU_FAILED, e });
    }
}


export function* watchMenu() {
    yield takeEvery(FETCH_MENU_REQUEST, handleFetchMenu);
}
```

Rootsaga.js:

```
export default function* Root() {
    yield all([
        fork(watchLoginRequest),
        fork(watchMenu),
    ])
}
```

the problem is it never enter to jwtmiddleware for any saga call. If I use redux thunk it runs properly.

The flow of this code is: before saga attempt to `fetchMenu` it will check for current jwt token if its need to be refresh (will update the token) or already expired (will redirect to login page).

is there any possible solution to make this code works? or any other flow for checking token for every call with redux saga?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm trying to implement a JWT token as well..

Answer (score 0):

In fact, saga-middleware is not just callback middleware, it is also live thread (In terms of JS engine, actually series of promise and timeout callbacks). So you should run it implicitly by using `run` function.

Example from documentation:

```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
)
sagaMiddleware.run(mySaga)
```

If interested, you can easily see it in source code - https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/src/internal/runSaga.js and so on. By similar reason sagas use generator function - to allow virtual saga processes contain async calls and transfer it's control to top layer (In analog to CO library)